# Image of left and right shift operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

> Find images of right and left shift operators respectively as
> $$R(x)=(0,x_1,x_2,\dots), \quad L(x)=(x_2,x_3,\dots) \quad \text{for }
>  x=(x_1,x_2,\dots).$$ Operators are defined on any sequence space such as $c_{00}, c_0,c,l_\infty, l_1$,

**Image of the right shift operator:** I have no idea how to write it down but it looks like the image is generated by infinite amount of vectors $$\langle (0,1,0,0,\dots), \space (0,0,1,0,\dots), \space (0,0,0,1,\dots), \dots\rangle.$$

**Image of the left shift operator:** similarly I think it could be written like this: $$\langle (1,0,0,0,\dots), \space (0,1,0,0,\dots), \space (0,0,1,0,\dots), \dots\rangle.$$
In this case, the image of left shift operator does not depend on $x_1$.

Anyone could tell me if I'm right or wrong? Thanks!

Comment: First of all, what exactly do you mean by "the image generated" by your list of vectors? The usual terms used in this context are "span" and "closed span", and it is important to make clear which you are referring to

Comment: @BenGrossmann well, yes, span would be the right term.

Comment: Second, instead of using a spanning set to describe the space, it's probably easiest to say that the image is the set of sequences in your space (which you didn't specify... is this $\ell^2$?) such that _____.

Comment: What is the *domain* of your operators?

Comment: @Karagum So in fact, the "spans" of your lists do not give the correct answers; what you need is the "closed span" for each set. But, per my second point, it's best to avoid discussing span for the purposes of this question

Comment: @BenGrossmann sorry about missing in my problem. I have updated my question with the spaces we are working in ($c_{00},c_0,c,l_\infty,l_1$).

Comment: @Karagum It would be best if you could choose a single space so that we could simplify discussion. Note for instance that the answer you gave (and clarified in the comments) is correct for $c_{00}$ but incorrect in all other cases.

Comment: @BenGrossmann this question is taken from Roman Vershynin "Lectures in Functional Analysis" page 6, Ex. 1.1.20 (link in this book https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.413.6711&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

It seems that the question wants us to find a general image for all of these spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I state in my first comment, one should avoid using the notion of "span" here since we end up having to be a bit careful about what we mean depending on the space in question.

With that said, the image for the left-shift operator will always be equal to the domain, i.e. "the entirety of the sequence space". The image for the right-shift operator will be "the set of sequences $(x_k)_{k=1}^\infty$ in the domain such that $x_1 = 0$".

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mix the names of the operators?

Comment: @Karagum I am sure